# Scraping show infinte loop above php 7.0?

Tags: php, yii2, simple-html-dom

```
 $url = 'https://site';
copy('https://site',  \Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/scrapping.html');
$response=\common\models\helpers\Scrapping\SimpleHtmlDom::fileGetHtml(\Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/scrapping.html');
var_dump($response);
exit();
```

**I am using `keltstr\simplehtmldom\ extension.`**

Here what i am doing is getting data and store it on my on server and scraped from my own local file.It execute infinite loop on above php
7.0 but working fine in php 7.0.Why this happen in php version.?
Same error when i directly use url in this function

```
// $response =   \keltstr\simplehtmldom\SimpleHTMLDom::fileGetHtml($url);
```

**Here is the recursion error output**
[image]

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here basically there is not problem in the library at all

The problem here for infinte loop is just in var_dump();

```
Here is the code
$response = file_get_html(url);
var_dump($response);
Here you will see the infinte loop in some server
```

So please do the rest of test without var_dump();
There is already the response in the code.

And one thing you have to care below php 7 you need to add 0 as offset

```
 foreach ($response->find('article',0) as $article) {
```

above php 7 the code will be

```
foreach ($response->find('article') as $article) {
```